# How to run sudo things as when using RVM

Tags: ruby, rvm, sudo

I'm testing out a library called `packetgen` on my machine. The problem is not the library itself; I'm trying to inject a single packet on my network just for a simple test. However when I inject it, it raises and error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    3: from packet.rb:5:in `<main>'
    2: from /home/COM-COM/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/packetgen-2.8.6/lib   /packetgen/packet.rb:240:in `to_w'
    1: from /home/COM-COM/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/packetgen-2.8.6/lib/ packetgen/header/eth.rb:95:in `to_w'
/home/COM_COM/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/packetgen-2.8.6/lib/packetgen /header/eth.rb:95:in `open_live': wlp2s0: You don't have permission to capture on that device (socket: Operation not permitted) (RuntimeError)
```

I need superuser privileges to capture or inject packets on the network, but if I run `sudo 'ruby packet.rb'` it raises and a different error because`packetgen` isn't installed on my machine's version of ruby. I'm running a version of ruby different from my machine's preinstalled version courtesy of RVM (Ruby Version Mananger). Does anyone have a workaround or a way to run this program without sudo? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RVM has sudo integration, see [here](https://rvm.io/integration/sudo).

> By default, when you use sudo your current shell environment is not
>   passed through to the session created by it, but RVM already allows
>   for easier access to sudo calls with rvmsudo. However, sudo's defaults
>   are very strict and you might end up getting password prompts on
>   commands that are set to use the sudo NOPASSWD directive.